# nls - Convergence failure: singular convergence (7)

Tags: r, statistics, nls

The following `nls` code throws the following error `Convergence failure: singular convergence (7)` for `fm2`(for `Data2`). But the same code for similar dataset works fine (`fm1` for `Data1`).

**Works Fine for this Data Set**

```
Data1 <-
structure(list(D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L),
    Y = c(11.6, 9.3, 10.7, 9.2, 7.8, 8, 8.6, 7.9, 7.7,
    7.6, 7.5, 7.5, 7.2, 7.3, 7, 6.5, 6.3, 5.7, 5.6, 6)), .Names = c("D",
"Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 20L))

fm1  <-
  nls(
      formula=Y~w*(1-(i*D/(100*(1+i*D/A))))
    , data=Data1
    , start=list(w=13, i=3, A=80)
    , algorithm="port"
    )
```

---

**Does not Work for this Data Set**

```
Data2 <-
structure(list(D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L),
    Y = c(10.8, 10.7, 8.4, 8.5, 8, 8, 8, 7.9, 7.9, 7.2,
    7.8, 7.2, 6.6, 6.5, 6.5, 6.4, 2.2, 4.5, 4.2, 6.2)), .Names = c("D",
"Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 21:40)

fm2  <-
  nls(
      formula=Y~w*(1-(i*D/(100*(1+i*D/A))))
    , data=Data2
    , start=list(w=13, i=3, A=80)
    , algorithm="port"
    )
```

Answer (score 7):

I think its having problems with your parameterization.  We can take advantage of linearlity by letting B be i/A, .lin1 = w and .lin2 = i*w in which case .lin1 and .lin2 enter linearly and using `alg=plinear` only the non-linear parameter needs a starting value:

```
> fo <- Y ~ cbind(1, -D/(100*(1+B*D)))
> nls(fo, Data, start = list(B = 3/80), alg = "plinear")
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ cbind(1, -D/(100 * (1 + B * D)))
   data: Data
       B    .lin1    .lin2 
-0.02217  9.26808 13.61471 
 residual sum-of-squares: 15.76

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.236e-06
```

From the result w = .lin1; i*w = .lin2 (so i = .lin2 / .lin1) and B = i/A (so A = i/B).

*REVISED* Improved the formulation.

Comment: So you think model is not identified or I've programmed it incorrectly. Same model works fine for other datasets.

Comment: The problem is the parameterization and also one can use plinear to take advantage of the linearity.  Also note that I have improved the formulation further.

Comment: Please see my edited question and give me a hand. Thanks

Comment: The answer provided already converges for both your data sets.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the parameters of two different models? Not obvious to me.

Comment: The answer explicitly gives the relationship.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Please

Comment: I have already provided the exact equations. What more can be said than giving the exact correspondence?

Comment: Thanks @ G. Grothendieck for your help. Now the question arises how to get the Standard Errors and P.values.

Comment: `summary(nls(...))` . Read up on the delta method for transformed parameters or try running the model with the original parameters using the know solution as the starting value and use `summary` on that.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316979/how-can-i-specify-a-relationship-between-parameter-estimates-in-lm/19325690#19325690 ;